# Angular 5 routing issue (redirect back to home)

Tags: angular, routes

I have a problem in an Angular 5 project. Im trying to navigate to a ClientListComponent from my LocationDetailComponent. I have the following in my HTML-code in LocationDetailComponent:

```
<a href class="cp" 
(click)="seeClients(ap.name);"> {{ ap.details.apclientcount }} 
</a></td>
```

LocationDetailComponent:

```
seeClients(ap): void {
    console.log(ap);
    this.router.navigate(['clients/' + ap]);
}
```

Routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'locations', component: LocationListComponent},
  {path: 'location/:id', component: LocationDetailComponent},          
  {path: 'clients/:id', component: ClientListComponent},
  {path: 'client/:id', component: ClientDetailComponent},
  {path: '404', component: Error404Component},
  // otherwise redirect to 404
  {path: '**', redirectTo: '/404'}
];
```

This works well when i do it from LocationListComponent to LocationDetailComponent, but when i go to ClientListComponent i see the Component for a second or two, then it redirects back to the HomeComponent. I cant understand why? Using the { enableTracing: true } option for RouterModule, i see this in the URL:

NavigationEnd {id: 4, url: "/clients/W0233-01-008", urlAfterRedirects: "/clients/W0233-01-008"}

This is correct, and loads the correct Component - but then suddenly "Navigated to http://localhost:4200/" appears, and it gets path '/'.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by not using the `<a href>` to create the link to the other component - using `<li href>` worked. Still curious as to why though..

Answer (score 0):

When you give anchor tag with href, browser automatically redirects you to the link you have given in href.
If you have used href to make cursor look as pointer, add a css class with cursor:pointer.